# Show split pane number

Tags: iterm2

Using something like 'Command + Number' to change focus on split panes can be very handy, way better than just cycling through panes using arrow keys or anything like that.

But I didn't manage to find any options that'd let iterm2 to tell me what number is every pane, that would make switching pane using pane number impossible to use when there's too many split panes.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer (Nov 15, 2019)**

1. From version 3.3: (Various pages of Preferences window has been modified for visual enhancement)

**Preferences -> Keys -> Navigation Shortcuts -> Shortcut to choose a split pane ->** *Select* "<kbd>⌘</kbd> Number" *option* and select **No shortcut** for other options.

2. Prior to version 3.3:

**Preferences -> Keys -> Navigation Shortcuts -> To switch split panes ->** *Select* "<kbd>⌘</kbd> Number" *option*.

---

**Old Answer**

Go to **iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Keys -> Navigation Shortcuts -> To switch split panes ->** *Select* "<kbd>⌘</kbd> Number" *option*.

The switching works like the same as browser tabs. i.e., You can switch from 1 to 8 using the numbers and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+9 to the last/ninth tab. Also make sure that no other shortcuts are bound to the same key combination (such as for switching tabs), which may override the preference setting.